# Can Vim be made simpler?

Tags: vim, user-interface

I have a 300MB file I want to edit, search, remove duplicate lines, compare 2 files, that sort of stuff. I tried Sublime Text 3, which was slow and crashed often. I [asked for recommendations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/411898/text-editor-to-handle-extremly-large-files) and was pointed to Vim.

But Vim is too complicated for me. I don't want to spend a lifetime learning to use a text editor. Can Vim be made simpler? I'm talking *simple* as in as Sublime or `nano`. I just don't want to memorize hundreds of commands.

I might want to re-enable those commands when I become a power user, but at the moment, they're too much to chew. Even just the [movement commands](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/8-essential-vim-editor-navigation-fundamentals/) are a handful.

Comment: You can use the graphical version, `gvim` for starters. It's often called `vim-gtk` when attempting to install the package.

Comment: In `vim`, press `i` to enter *insert mode*. You now have a normal text editor. You can already use the arrow keys normally, even in *normal mode*. I think this question is too broad.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_Vim_like_an_IDE

Comment: Run `evim` (easy vim)

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - nice, never seen that one before!

Comment: It doesn't take a lifetime to learn `vim`. Have you tried `vimtutor`?

Comment: It doesn't take a lifetime to learn piano either, lol. I love vim but I would hate to have to start from nothing with it.  The first thing you should do is `set nocp` so you can at least tell when you are in INSERT mode.  Put it in `~/.vimrc`. There is a `:help`.

Comment: I don't fully agree on the order of concepts presentation but you have an incredible good job at [vim-adventures](http://vim-adventures.com).

Comment: vim really isn't that hard... the basics are `i`, `esc` `gg` `G` `d[opt: number]` + space or `d`... and then some `:E` or `:%s` once you get into editing `z` + `{}` and `zd` and of course `y`[ank] `x`, `p` and `v`=> select stuff then `"*y` for example... ok, so there are a few things to keep in mind, but it's really not as hard as it seems at first, and vim has _excellent_ documentation (including an interactive man page and a great wiki)

Comment: For such a task it is probably better to use a scripting language like Perl or Python, or perhaps even awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try [Cream - A modern configuration of the powerful and famous Vim, Cream is for Microsoft Windows, GNU/Linux, and FreeBSD](http://cream.sourceforge.net/).

Also, I'd encourage you to at least try out plain Vim (no plugins yet, but do make extensive use of the built-in `:help`) for at least a week. `vimtutor` is a great start; you don't need to memorize dozens of commands for most editing tasks.

- Every IT professional and enthusiast should have at least a minimal knowledge of *vi*.
- You can decide much better after actually using it. (Do the same test-drive with Emacs, too!)

Comment: Cream worked fine, I also installed vim to learn it, but cream is what i needed!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ man evim
NAME
       evim - easy Vim, edit a file with Vim and setup for modeless editing

SYNOPSIS
       evim [options] [file ..]
       eview

DESCRIPTION
       eVim starts Vim and sets options to make it behave like a modeless edi‐
       tor.  This is still Vim but used as  a  point-and-click  editor.   This
       feels  a lot like using Notepad on MS-Windows.  eVim will always run in
       the GUI, to enable the use of menus and toolbar.

       Only to be used for people who really can't work with Vim in the normal
       way.  Editing will be much less efficient.

       eview  is  the  same, but starts in read-only mode.  It works just like
       evim -R.

       See vim(1) for details about Vim, options, etc.

       The 'insertmode' option is set to be able to type text directly.
       Mappings are setup to make Copy and  Paste  work  with  the  MS-Windows
       keys.   CTRL-X  cuts  text,  CTRL-C copies text and CTRL-V pastes text.
       Use CTRL-Q to obtain the original meaning of CTRL-V.

OPTIONS
       See vim(1).
```

(if you have the gtk enabled variant of `vim` installed, `evim` will be available as well)

Comment: The "gtk enabled variant" is `gvim`.

Answer (score 0):

Vim by default allows the arrow keys to be used, so you don't have to limit movement to the `hjkl` keys.  If you want vim easy mode, one option is to just learn the very basic commands.

- arrow keys to move
- `i` to enter insert mode (so you can enter text)
- `<esc>` key to enter command mode (so you can save and exit)
- `ZZ` in command mode - saves and exits.

That much will let you move around, edit, save and exit.

I do recommend learning more of vim, as the editing commands in normal mode are quite intuitive.

---

There are other tools you can use for your non-editing tasks:

> search

See tools like `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `perl` (probably overkill).  The last 3 tools on that list can also edit via search/replace or other methods.

> remove duplicate lines

If you file is sorted, `uniq` can remove duplicates.

> compare 2 files

`diff` is the tool for this job.